# What's the equivalent of clrscr(); in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to write a simple script file to display the employee name in a given department name the department name given is case insensitive ,after executing the script, the commands are not displayed.

I use SQL *PLUS and what I did so far is

```
EDIT script // script is the file name the default extension is .SQL
```

and inside the script file I wrote the following

```
SET VERIFY OFF

SELECT Ename, dname
FROM   emp, dept
WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno
AND UPPER(Dname) = UPPER('&dname');

SET VERIFY ON
```

then on SQL *Plus

```
START script
```

The query works fine but I don't know how to do this part "after executing the script, the commands are not displayed.
"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe are you looking for:

```
SET ECHO OFF
```

An other option would be to start *SQL*Plus* with the `-S` (silent) option on the command line. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#sthref223):

> **-S[ILENT]**
>
> Suppresses all SQL*Plus information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner normally displayed when you start SQL*Plus.

---

As about the question as titled:

> What's the equivalent of clrscr()

If you are using an ANSI terminal, using the [ANSI escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) <kbd>esc</kbd>`[2J` should clear your screen:

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
VAR ANSI_TERM_CLEAR VARCHAR2 (10)
BEGIN SELECT CHR(27)||'[2J' INTO :ANSI_TERM_CLEAR FROM DUAL; END;
/
PRINT :ANSI_TERM_CLEAR
```

Comment: I tried SET ECHO OFF, I didn't notice any changes, the previous queries are still there and the screen isn't cleared? isn't that what SET ECHO OFF supposed to do?